# Ethereum POW or POS

Tags: go-ethereum

Hello just wanted to know wether ethereum is now POS or still fully POW by this date? If it is still POW do you guys know when it shall become POS? When will casper be fully and officially be implemented?

Thanks

Comment: Apparently there's no exact date announced. Some articles suggest that it would be in late this year.

Comment: So it is still fully POW?

Comment: Yes, AFAIK, Casper FFG, the hybrid of POW/POS is still under testing

Answer (score 2):

As if this date (June 3, 2018), Ethereum is fully POW. Casper FFG, which is hybrid POW/POS, has a test net that has been running for a few months, but there is no date for its deployment to the mainnet. The hope (I would think) is to include it in the next hard fork, called Constantinople.

FFG is not full POS. The current full POS work goes under the name CBC POS (Correct-by-Construction). That work is further out than the next hard fork, to be sure.